# Prove, preferably with elementary methods, that $\int_0^\infty x^5 e^{-x^4}~dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{8}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

In the final question of the MIT Integration Bee $2020$ qualifier exam, the participants were asked to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty x^5 e^{-x^4}~dx$$
and in the [solutions](http://www.mit.edu/%7Epax/pdf/qualifying_round_2020_answers.pdf) they give the answer as $$\frac{\sqrt\pi}{8}$$
Most, if not all the other questions can be completed with the use of elementary methods and functions, but I could not solve this question. The integrand is strongly suggestive of the Gamma function and the Gaussian integral, but I am not competent with these yet, so I couldn't employ them to evaluate the integral.

So, how would I solve this integral? If you must resort to non-elementary functions and results and techniques, then so be it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You will need to use the result $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ somehow. There are elementary proofs of this result.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think I've almost got it now. thank you, I'll post my progress.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh using your tip I got the result, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty x^5 e^{-x^4}~dx$$
Let $x^2= u$.

$$\frac12\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-u^2}~du$$

$$\frac12\int_0^\infty u \cdot u e^{-u^2}~du$$
Now use integration by parts and use that $\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}~du=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Really, letting $x^4=u$ gets it in one. You immediately obtain one quarter of the Gaussian and so the answer follows @A-LevelStudent

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt t$ to make
$$I=\int x^5 e^{-x^4}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int t^2\,e^{-t^2} \,dt$$ One integration by parts to get
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{8} \text{erf}(t)-\frac{1}{4}t \, e^{-t^2} $$ and then the result for the definite integral.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=-\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} 
{x}^{2} d\left(e^{-x^{4}}\right) \\
& \stackrel{IBP}{=} -\left[\frac{x^{2} e^{-x^{4}}}{4}\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} 2 x e^{-x^{4}} d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^{4}} d x 
\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}} d y \quad \text {, where } y=x^{2} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac12\int x^4e^{-x^4}dx^2=\frac12\int y^2e^{-y^2}dy=\frac12\int y\,ye^{-y^2}dy=-\frac14ye^{-y^2}+\frac14\int e^{-y^2}dy.$$

Comment: Crossed with Forester.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: nope, read carefully..

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice the $dx^2$.

Answer (score 0):

With $I(a)=\int_0^\infty xe^{-ax^4}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac14\sqrt{\frac\pi a}$

$$\int_0^\infty x^5 e^{-x^4}~dx = -I’(1)=-\frac{d}{da}\left( \frac14\sqrt{\frac\pi a}\right)\bigg|_{a=1}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{8}
$$